# How do I make changes to emails sent out of OpenCart?

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to update the emails that are sent out of OpenCart. Specifically, the email sent to customers when I update their orders and they get a status update.

I have tried a lot of different strategies but despite everything I do, nothing changes and the email stays the same. This is what I have tried:

- I have edited catalog\view\theme\default\template\mail\order_edit.twig
- I have deleted this same file off the server
- I have deleted catalog\controller\mail\order.php off the server
- I have turned off template cache
- I have gone into storage\cache and deleted all files
- I have edited catalog\language\en-gb\mail\order_edit.php to change the text
- I have refreshed template cache, SASS cache and modifications cache
- I deleted the changes made to the order_edit.twig from the database in the oc_theme table

No matter what I do the email works and looks exactly as it always has. Why does it work when I delete the files and caches? Why aren't my changes being honoured?

I'm using OpenCart 3.0.2.0